# How do I change the color of the title in a beamerposter?

Tags: beamerposter

I'm using the beamerposter package to make a conference poster.  Specifically I'm using the quite popular template provided here:

http://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster

How do I change the color of the title of the poster?

Also, how do I change the color of the author names?

It's probably easiest to just download the template for a generic poster at the link I provided for a minimal working example.

Answer (score 2):

The template uses a file called beamerthemeconfposter.sty, which is included in the zip file when you download this template.  The file beamerthemeconfposter.sty contains the line

```
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{jblue}\Huge{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[0.5ex]}
```

You can replace "jblue" with another color like "red" to change the color of the title.

The color of the author names can be changed similarly.

Comment: If I'm using any terms incorrectly (such as "template", perhaps), please correct me.

Comment: Rather than needing to change that line in beamerthemeconfposter.sty, better to duplicate the relevant line with the appropriate changes somewhere in the .tex file after the theme has been loaded.